# Create certain number with image format PHP

Tags: php, image

I have a number stored in txt file (like 2353), I need to read that number and transform this number to image (totalimage.png), but I want to use my custom numbers image (1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png...) to create this image...

I dont know how to create this sequence using the custom numbers and after merge all to only one image (totalimage.png).

Someone could show me example of code to do that? It must be in PHP, can't use Js.

Thanks for your time =]

Answer (score 0):

It's like puzzle? If u want show total "image" result from other little images u can do something like this:

```
$number = (int) file_get_contents('number.txt');
(string) $number;
$number_len = strlen($number);
for($i=0;$i<$number_len;$i++) {
  echo $number[$i].'.png';
}
```

This will show all images in row.

Comment: Hey, Like this: http://www.contador-gratis.com/img/opcao04.jpg

Comment: Yes u can reach this visualy in html document.

Comment: but how to load the parts of the number ? like 0.png 1.png how to insert this argument in your code?

Comment: @kevinhf35 u write about store number in file, and in code its read number from file first.